# How to copy directories in docker container except any one directory?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-swarm

I have some directories/files, I want to copy all directories/files except 
`my_data` directory from host to Docker container  Below command is working fine to copy all the directories/files in the container:

```
docker cp ./ container_name:/my-dir
```

How can I copy all the directories/files from host to container except `my_data` dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no such way to do a `--exclude` while doing a `docker cp`. If you have a `Dockerfile`, you can achieve this by using `.dockerignore`.

Below is what i can suggest now as a quick hack/workaround -

```
mkdir /tmp/to_be_copied
rsync -avzh ./ /tmp/to_be_copied --exclude my_data
docker cp /tmp/to_be_copied 0132381bc8d6:/my_dir
rm -rf /tmp/to_be_copied
```

You copy your folder structure to a different location using `rsync`(pre-installed in many OS) with the directory `my_data` excluded. Post this you can easily use `docker cp` with the newly created directory, don't forget to cleanup at the end. Hope it helps!